# Need advice solving a modeling problem

Tags: modeling, topology

I am stuck trying to solve this problem, I need some advice.

.blend file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qarlafx6sbzkhf/camaro_tail.blend?dl=0
I am on this situation:

[image]
As you can see I hace a "weird" quad there.
[image]
I would like to have two proper quads instead. But I can't figure out a way of doing it.

I tried this and that's what I want on that side:
[image]
But then I have a problem on the other side:
[image]

I extrude the whole edge to make quads, but the problem keeps on repeating.

[image]

Do you have any ideas?

I would like to keep a proper topology, all quads. But the problem is the quads doesn't pair on both sides.

What I'm modeling is this, without the tail light, that I will model separately. So it's a slot for tail light.

Thanks!
[image]
Edit: New attempt as moonboots adviced:I end with and ngon because of the upper loop cuts
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do it this way? Do you plan to use a *Subdivision Surface* modifier? In that case you'll need to bevel your angles. Also it's sometimes ok to use tris, as long as the render is good...

[image]

Edit: Here is one way to fix the problem you show:

[image]

Comment: Yes I plan to use subdivision. The problem with your solution is that it is still not a quad, at least for me, because of the new edge loop. I will ad a picture to the question explaining it.

Comment: you can easily get rid of these 2 vertices with a reduction of topology

Comment: Can you please show me your idea? I can't figure it out, thnks!

Comment: for example see: https://topologyguides.com/assets/img/163679954765_0.png ... if you don't manage to reduce, please share your new file

Comment: I've edited my answer, if you really need these 2 edges on the top here is a way to get rid of them, I'm sure it is not the best topology for your object but it's just to show how you can reduce topology